# Generic UIView confirmable function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I want to add a simple function to UIView which is almost the same as UIView's insertSubview. Where T should be UIView and it's subclasses. For example UIButton.

```
func insertSubviewUnder<T: UIView>(belowSubview: UIView) -> T -> T {
    return { item in
        self.insertSubview(item, belowSubview: belowSubview)
        println("TYPE: \(item.dynamicType)")
        return item
    }
}
```

Then:

```
let xs = [UIButton(), UIButton(), UIButton()]
println(xs.dynamicType)
println(xs.map(insert).dynamicType)
```

And the result is:

```
Swift.Array<UIButton>
TYPE: UIButton
TYPE: UIButton
TYPE: UIButton
Swift.Array<UIView>
```

So my question is in the last map output. I want to see `<UIButton>` instead of `<UIView>`.

Comment: `println(xs.map(insert).dynamicType)` does not compile. Also I cant understand what `insertSubviewUnder` has to do with your example

Comment: let insert = insertSubviewUnder(someView)

Comment: Is someView in `insertSubviewUnder` UIButton or UIView ?

Comment: doesn't matter. This is just a parent for views from array

Answer (score 0):

By storing function into insert variable the dynamic type of this generic function cannot be determined from any input parameter so by default will be `UIView -> UIView`. By passing function directly into your map function will lead to desired result

```
println(xs.map(insertSubviewUnder(someView)).dynamicType)
```

Comment: yes, but how to make it the same with insert variable?

Comment: As described above, Im afraid you cant do that